# Display areas of unmanaged entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a custom entity in CRM 4.0 called Mark. Areas that display this entity is none. After importing this organization to CRM2011 beta, i tried to make this entity appear in Workplace area, so i navigated to the settings >>Solutions>>Entities then i checked Workplace in areas that display this entity, Then saved and published the form.

The unexpected happened, i didn't find the Mark entity in the workplace area.

I tried to refresh, restarted the IIS, closed the brower, .. nothing changed, any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> [...] Then saved and published the **form**.

For your changes to be effective, you must publish the whole solution or at least the entity and the **Sitemap component** under Client extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Make your customizations in the site map portion of the customizations.xml and import and publish all customizations.  Then it will show up wherever you choose to put it.